# Get type that I may assign to dereferenced iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have function(Actually it's partially specialized)

```
template<typename T>
T generate(){

}
```

To use it I have to implicitly type template type e.g

```
int v = generate<int>();
```

Now I want to write function, that gets Output iterator and generate `n` values using this function.

```
template<typename OI>
fill(size_t n, OI it){

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        *(it++) = generate<__TYPE???__>();
    }
}
```

I know that for iterators that have actually values, that are pointed out to, there `value_type`, that shows it. But if I get for example `back_insert_iterator` `value_type` is void, that isn't what I want.

So, Is it way to get this type?

Comment: You want to re-implement [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) and [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not exactly

Answer (score 3):

Output iterators purposely don't need to have a `value_type`. You can't automatically retrieve what type can be inserted into the sequence. There might even be several first-class sequence types for a given iterator.

One workaround would be simply to require that iterators used *with your function* supply a `value_type` member or have a useful `* iterator` dereference operation. But as you've observed, `std::back_insert_iterator` fails these requirements.

The better alternative is to take two template parameters.

```
template<typename T, typename OI>
fill(size_t n, OI it);
```

This doesn't allow for deduction of `T`, so you need

```
fill< int >( intvec.size(), std::back_inserter( intvec ) );
//    ^^^ explicit, but the iterator type is still deduced
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can change `generate()` to take a reference as an output parameter instead of using a return value, then the compiler can work out what the type is for you based on what you pass in, eg:

```
template<typename T>
void generate(T &value)
{
    value = ...;
}
```

.

```
int v;
generate(v);
```

.

```
generate(*(it++));
```

Comment: `it = it++ = *it` for back_inserter

Comment: @RiaD: You meant `decltype(id) == decltype(id++) == decltype(*it)`, didn't you? Yes, it is.